# Component that fetches API is not working in production after deploying with Vercel

Tags: reactjs, vercel

The api fetches and renders an activity when I am in localhost300 but when I deploy the app and then test it live the activity does not render. I am using Vercel's auto deploy whhich pulls from Github. Do you know why it would render in localhost but not in production? It may also be worth noting this api does not require a Key.

Here is the component causing the issue:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Activities() {
  const [activity, setActivity] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedActivity = localStorage.getItem("activity");
    if (storedActivity) {
      setActivity(storedActivity);
    }
  }, []);
  

  const handleButtonClick = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/");
      const data = await response.json();
      setActivity(data.activity);
      localStorage.setItem("activity", data.activity);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex h-fit sticky flex-col items-center bg-opacity-40 bg-white top-[80px] rounded-lg text-black text-center border-b border-gray-600">
      <div className="flex flex-col py-2 px-6 h-[150px] w-[200px] overflow-hidden">
        <button
          className="bg-green-500 hover:shadow-xl text-white font-bold py-2 px-6 mb-2 rounded focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-600"
          onClick={handleButtonClick}
        >
          Get Activity
        </button>
        <span className="text-sm text-black lg:text-base xl:text-lg">{activity}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Activities;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using HTTP and should have been using HTTPS.